# How do you define a non-generic recursive datatype in Idris?

Tags: idris

This is literally my first line of Idris code. When I looked up the documentation, all appeared proper:

```
Idris> data T = Foo Bool | Bar (T -> T)
(input):1:6:
  |
1 | data T = Foo Bool | Bar (T -> T)
  |      ^
unexpected reserved data
expecting dependent type signature
```

This makes me think I may need to declare `T` to be a symbol in some fashion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works as expected inside an Idris source file.  At the REPL however, declarations need to be prefixed with the `:let` command:

```
:let data T = Foo Bool | Bar (T -> T)
```

Thanks for the question. I learned something trying to answer it.